# Changing the UIbezierpath Arc with gradient layer IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to fill the arc with gradient color only in the arc Can you any one provide solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFXz9.png)

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIBezierPath *arc = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:barCenter radius:barRadius startAngle:fmodf(MIN_ANGLE+M_PI, 2*M_PI) endAngle:fmodf(MAX_ANGLE+M_PI, 2*M_PI) clockwise:YES];
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, kArcThickness);


CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor(ctx, 0.6, 1.0);
CGContextAddPath(ctx, arc.CGPath);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);




// knob to move the slider

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, knobCenter.x, knobCenter.y, knobRadius, 0, 2*M_PI, 1);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFill);
```

Comment: what output do you need..?

Comment: i need a arc with line width of 10 and in that arc color needs to be gradient color

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code..

```
//list of components
CGFloat components[8] = {
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,     // Start color - Blue
    1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };   // End color - Violet

CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, components, NULL, 2);
CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

//Gradient direction
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

//Draw the gradient
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: It is for rectangle of the frame i only need for the arc